# Download specific files from AWS S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: python, boto3

I am trying to download to a local machine specific files from an S3 bucket. 
The Bucket structure is as follow:

```
BucketName/TT/2019/07/23/files.pdf
```

I want to download all files under:

```
BucketName/TT/2019/07/23
```

How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried? What issues have you encountered?

Comment: I am not really a dev, I am more looking for suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('BucketName')

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='TT/2019/07/23/'):
    filename = obj.key.split("/").pop()
    if filename != "":
        print('Downloading ', obj.key)
        bucket.download_file(obj.key, filename)
```

Note that you will need to configure aws first by setting up authentication credentials. Please refer to the [quick start guide](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/quickstart.html) to see how to do that.